# To Create a dynamic Carousel in Facebook Messenger Bot

Tags: node.js, facebook-messenger-bot

To create a carousel we should add more elements in element array of payload

```
"payload": {
  "template_type":"generic",
  "elements":[
    <GENERIC_TEMPLATE>,
    <GENERIC_TEMPLATE>,
    ...
  ]
}
```

But in those templates I want to add a dynamic values that i am getting from either db or some api's

example,

```
messageData = {
              // text: "Enter the venue name"
              "attachment": {
                "type": "template",
                "payload": {
                  "template_type": "generic",
                  "elements": [{  
                    "title": "sample",
                    "subtitle":"We'\''ve got the right hat for everyone.",
                    "buttons": [
                      {
                        "type": "postback",
                        "title": data[i],
                        "payload": "Book Me a Venue",
                      }
                    ]
                  },{  
                    "title": "sample",
                    "subtitle":"We'\''ve got the right hat for everyone.",
                    "buttons": [
                      {
                        "type": "postback",
                        "title": data[i],
                        "payload": "Book Me a Venue",
                      }
                    ]
                  },{  
                    "title": "sample",
                    "subtitle":"We'\''ve got the right hat for everyone.",
                    "buttons": [
                      {
                        "type": "postback",
                        "title": data[i],
                        "payload": "Book Me a Venue",
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
                }
              }
            }
```

Instead of those hardcoded values i want to send dynamic values
Any help would be useful

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. You would just set those value dynamically before you send the POST to the Messenger Platform API. If you mean you want to dynamically change them after the message is sent, that's not possible.

Comment: actually it is,i found a way!, maybe you didn't understand the problem............ now i can get the values from my api and iterate it to my carousel

Comment: Yes, that's why I said I was not sure what the problem is =)

Comment: Can you share your code of how/where you iterated through the data? and where data[i] is coming from? Thanks.

Comment: @fardin, the data[i] is coming from an api call, i will update the code, the api  returns a bunch of json values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate though an object array, you need to do it this way....

```
console.log("-------2222222", data.length)
        var objArray = []
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var object = {
            "title": data[i].venueName,

            "buttons": [
              {
                "type": "postback",
                "title": "Select",
                "payload": data[i].id,
              }
            ]
          }
          objArray.push(object)
        }
        messageData = {
          "attachment": {
            "type": "template",
            "payload": {
              "template_type": "generic",
              "elements": objArray
            }
          }
        }
```